# Two ways to initialize an array. What happens with each one?

Tags: c, arrays

There are two ways (at least) to initialize an array in C. What is the difference between

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ;
```

and:

```
int array[100] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ;
```

I do not mean in means of memory allocation. Perhaps the thing that provoked this question would be useful so as to understand my question.

I wanted to get the length of an int array by iterating trough it. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ;
int i = 0 ; // i is length
while( array[i] ) {
    printf("%d\n" , array[i] ) ;
    i++ ;
}
printf("%d\n" , i) ;
```

And I noticed that when I used array[] the length sometimes was wrong because of some sort of overflow , but when I used array[100] the length was always right. What is the difference between these two?
Has it got something to do with '\0' character ?

Comment: You are printing the array until an element is 0, but if you don't set to zero the last member no one will do for you. It hasn't anything to do with the number inside the brackets.

Comment: so if you use array[] the 0 is not set but if you use something bigger like array[100] the 0 is set in the end?

Comment: You must set it manually (or compute the length using sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])). If you set the array lenght to something bigger, the remaining elements are 0. Sorry for not reading properly before.

Comment: It IS 0. Sorry, my mind don't work very hard at night :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the array without specifying its size the compiler infers it from the initializer (in this case, the length would be 9). The memory locations immediately after the array have unspecified contents since noone bothered giving them specific values, and that's why you get the "overflow" behavior -- this is technically *undefined* behavior, but the result is a very common way for the compiler vendor to implement "undefined".

When you explicitly specify the size the compiler initializes the array with as many elements as you have provided, then fills the remaining space with zeroes.

In both cases the behavior is according to the standard.

Comment: so in array[] case there is no '\0' ?

Comment: @DoomProg In `int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`, there are no `0`.  In `int array[100] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`, there are 91 `0`.

Comment: The memory locations after the array don't exist (as far as C is concerned), trying to read them causes undefined behaviour. They might not even exist physically either, e.g. if this array is right at the end of the memory space. "unspecified" means it's OK to read them but you may get various values back -- which is not the case here.

Comment: Compiler vendors don't really implement "undefined" .. they implement "defined" plus any extensions they want to add; and anything else falls where it may .

Comment: @MattMcNabb: they "implement" UB implicitly since they know what their codegen will do when its preconditions are violated by the code. I agree that without quotes it's somewhat misleading.

Comment: @DoomProg Arrays aren't null terminated AFAIK. You have to track the size.

Answer (score 3):

You can programmatically get the size of the array with the `sizeof` operator. So in this case, you can do `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)` to get the actual size. The sizeof operator is handled by the compiler, which will insert the correct size constant at compile time.

Note that iterating through the array until you get to a false result is undefined behavior and should not be done.

Pertaining to your original question, @Jon is correct; either array size specifier is correct and will yield the same results.

Comment: Note that this approach only works for arrays allocated on the stack. This will not work for arrays allocated on the heap.

Comment: Absolutely. I was responding based on the example provided.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no null terminating character in arrays of numbers, only array of char. So if your array was a c style string, your code would have successfully found the length